# Check for diagonal win in connect 4 for java using a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a connect 4 program for java. I know how to check for horizontal and vertical wins, but I can't seem to figure out how to check for a diagonal win. Here is my program:

```
private int[][] board= new int[6][7];

public int connectFour(int[][] temp){
    int pOneh= 0;
    int pTwoh= 0;
    int pOnev= 0;
    int pTwov= 0;
    for(int r=0; r<temp.length; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<temp[r].length; c++){
            //For Player 1 Horozontal check
            if(temp[r][c]== 1){
                pOneh++;
            }
            else{
                pOneh=0;
            }

            //For Player 2 Horozontal Check
            if(temp[r][c]== 2){
                pTwoh++;
            }
            else{ 
                pTwoh=0;
            }

            if(pOneh==4)return 1;
            if(pTwoh==4)return 2;
        }
    }

    for(int c= 0; c<6; c++){
        for(int r= 0; r<temp.length; r++){
            //For player 1 Vertical Check
            if(temp[r][c]==1){ 
                pOnev++;
            }
            else{
                pOnev=0;
            }
            //For player 2 Vertical Check
            if(temp[r][c]==2){
                pTwov++;
            }
            else{
                pTwov=0;
            }
        }
        if(pOnev==4) return 1;
        if(pTwov==4) return 2;
    }
```

//Need a diagonal check here

```
    return 0; 
}
```

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way to think about this is whether there is a way you could iterate with two `for` loops that would iterate by diagonals and check for items in a row instead of vertical vs. horizontal?

Comment: Draw your grid in a notebook, and look for relation between diagonal cells. This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal